# One column text under chapter title in memoir twocolumn mode?

Tags: memoir, two-column, multicol

I want to have one column text underneath the chapter name in twocolumn mode (where the majority of the text is in twocolumn).

I can't. Even using `onecolabstract` doesn't do it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{memoir}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}
One column text that goes across the entire top part

And the rest of the text formatted in two columns
\end{document}
```

I want the "One column" line to be as wide as the chapter title. Is it possible without loading the `multicol` package? The following shows what I want (using `multicol` - but I'd prefer not to load it unless there's no other way).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's one... round-about way - setting the first paragraph as part of the chapter header:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\usepackage{ragged2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e

\let\oldafterchaptertitle\afterchaptertitle% Store \afterchaptertitle
\newcommand{\afterchapterparagraph}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{% Update \afterchaptertitle
    \oldafterchaptertitle% Old \afterchaptertitle
    \normalfont\normalsize\justifying #1% Set after-chapter paragraph
    \global\let\afterchaptertitle\oldafterchaptertitle}}% Restore \afterchaptertitle

\begin{document}

\afterchapterparagraph{\lipsum[1]}
\chapter{Example}

\hspace*{\parindent}%
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

This does require you to specify the first paragraph *before* setting the actual `\chapter`. I guess a better interface is also possible.

[`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) provides the means to restore the paragraph alignment to be justified.