# How do I find memoir's margin settings for twocolumn mode?

Tags: margins, memoir, two-column, multicol

I have a long document that I don't want to use `twocolumn` mode for, but I like the margins it uses. I'm going to manually use `multicol` to create two columns instead (so I can easily have footnotes and other things be a single column).

Compare

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

to

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The second has much wider default margins. Is there a way to see what the margins are in a given `memoir` document and copy them into another one?

(The reason I'm doing this is because [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164841/one-column-text-under-chapter-title-in-memoir-twocolumn-mode/) leads me to believe that the `twocolumn` option doesn't really do what I need.

Comment: Although this question was for KOMA-Script see this answer: [Overview of Margins in KOMA Script/TypeArea](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51497) and test the packages.

Comment: Oh, `layout` is wrong, and `layouts` lacks relevant information.

Comment: Those get me closer to what I was asking about, but now I suspect I'm asking the wrong question. Since all I'm trying to do is get full-page-width footnotes (like `multicol` does), perhaps that's what I should aim for.

Comment: @Speravir Do those packages work independently of KOMA-Script? Could you use them with the standard LaTeX classes in conjunction with `geometry`?

Comment: @cfr: They should. Both are not from KOMA-Script, just the question was for it.

Comment: @Speravir Excellent!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memoir` offers facilities which I think provide the information you want (p25 of the documentation).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\settypeoutlayoutunit{mm}% note: needs to come *first* to have any effect (documentation is wrong)
\typeoutlayout
\typeoutstandardlayout
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Then the output includes this information:

```
******************************************************
Stock height and width: 279.39671mm by 215.89746mm
Top and edge trims: 0mm and 0mm
Page height and width: 279.39671mm by 215.89746mm
Text height and width: 192.77344mm by 164.83272mm
Spine and edge margins: 20.47931mm and 30.58543mm
Upper and lower margins: 43.80676mm and 42.8165mm
Headheight and headsep: 5.0961mm and 6.98476mm
Footskip: 10.54367mm
Columnsep and columnseprule: 3.51456mm and 0mm
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 3.51456mm and 16.86987mm
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 3.51456mm and 16.86987mm
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 3.51456mm and 16.86987mm
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 5.0961mm and 0mm
Sidebarheight: 192.12323mm
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 3.51456mm and 16.86987mm
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 5.0961mm and 192.12323mm
******************************************************


******************************************************
Page height and width: 279.39671mm by 215.89746mm
Text height and width: 192.77344mm by 164.83272mm
Oddside and evenside margins: -4.92038mm and 4.92038mm
Topmargin and footskip: 6.3262mm and 10.54367mm
Headheight and headsep: 5.0961mm and 6.98476mm
Columnsep and columnseprule: 3.51456mm and 0mm
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 3.51456mm and 16.86987mm
******************************************************
```

So I think you want something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\textwidth}{164.83272mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{3.51456mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{16.86987mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-4.92038mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{4.92038mm}
\settypeoutlayoutunit{mm}
\typeoutlayout
\typeoutstandardlayout
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In the image below the pages are reversed from normal positioning i.e. my viewer puts the odd pages on the left rather than the right - hence the odd spacing effect.

[image: Single column with twocolumn spacing]

Note that this flies in the face of `memoir`'s raison d'être...

Comment: Ah, I've seen that. However, those values seem to NOT actually be set in `pt` but in something else. What is exactly `794.96999pt` - it doesn't seem to be an exact number of inches.

Comment: Oh I see - those aren't postscript points.

Comment: I actually thought there would be something, because `layouts` is originally from Peter Wilson like `memoir` originated from him, too.

Comment: @bombcar: Postscript points are known as big points (bp) in TeX world.

Comment: @bombcar See edits. In fact, you need to set the units before the other commands - the documentation is wrong. It only seemed to work because `pt` is default. I've switched to `mm` as this is a lot clearer. Note that the numbers are not integers because TeX defaults to `letterpaper` which isn't specified in `mm`. The `pt` numbers were correct. Just it is more obvious in 'real' units.

Comment: @Speravir One advantage of this method is that it also gives you the dimensions in `memoir`'s 'native' layout variables which may be nicer to use for replicating elements of the layout in non-twocolumn documents.