# Make footnote span entire text width in `twocolumn` mode in `memoir`

Tags: footnotes, memoir, two-column

I am trying to use the `twocolumn` option from `memoir` but it is also formatting the footnotes into two columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The Example}
Some simple text\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

I want the footnotes to span the bottom of the page, similar to how it looks if I use the `multicol` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The Example}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Some simple text\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

But I'd rather not use the `multicol` package here, unless it is the correct thing to do (I'd have to manually wrap each chapter in a `\begin{multicols}` block and use what I learned from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165807) to mimic the margins.) Is it possible to make footnotes in `twocolumn` mode span the entire page?

Comment: You could probably do it with the float package, but it would be a lot of work to set it up.

Comment: Yeah, I think the best is to turn off `twocolumn`, adjust the margins as required, and use `multicols`. It gets what I want.

Answer (score 6):

It has been over 5 years since you asked this question and I still have not found a solution which spans the entire text width with multiple columns, but Frank Mittelbach just released the ftnright.sty package which places all footnotes at the bottom of the right column to at least avoid the "different height footnotes on the same page" abomination.

```
\usepackage{ftnright}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now all I have to do is remember what I was working on five years ago ...

Comment: @bombcar, have you got solution for span footnotes across the mutiple columns? if yes can you post the answer if possible?, so that i can refer you answer, i am also facing issue to print the span footnotes across the columns

Comment: It's been seven years and I can't even find the project. I suspect I gave up on two column and went with a large margin instead.