# Footnote missing but not footnotemark memoir twocolumn mixed with onecolumn

Tags: footnotes, memoir, two-column

In order to use onecolumn after Chapter title I used the macro **afterchapterparagraph** posted elsewhere to keep in the same page the text that follows the chapter title, because the twocolumn statement forces a pagebreak.  Footnotes entered in that text does not show, although the footnote mark shows properly. multicol is not a solution for me as it shows footnotes as single column.  I prefer to keep the base twocolumn memoir class

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ragged2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e


\let\oldafterchaptertitle\afterchaptertitle% Store \afterchaptertitle
\newcommand{\afterchapterparagraph}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{% Update \afterchaptertitle
        \oldafterchaptertitle% Old \afterchaptertitle
        \normalfont\normalsize\justifying #1% Set after-chapter paragraph
        \global\let\afterchaptertitle\oldafterchaptertitle}
    }% Restore \afterchaptertitle

\begin{document}

\afterchapterparagraph{
    \textbf{Abstract.}  
    \lipsum[1][1] Someone\footnote{Unknown Author} said: 
    \lipsum[1][2-7]\newline
    \centerline{\textit{htpp://imposiblewebsite.com/misinformation/news}}\\
    \par
}
\chapter*{Interesting Topic}

\lipsum[2] Note: \footnote{The reader must understand this note is important}\par
\lipsum[3] Warning:\footnote{Read carefully, hiden information about fees as follows: \lipsum[3][1-5]}\par
\lipsum[3]\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you say where you found the code for `\afterchapterparagraph`. Thanks.

Comment: \afterchangeparagraph by #werner at
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164841/one-column-text-under-chapter-title-in-memoir-twocolumn-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \footnotemark and \footnotetext:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{ragged2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e


\let\oldafterchaptertitle\afterchaptertitle% Store \afterchaptertitle
\newcommand{\afterchapterparagraph}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{% Update \afterchaptertitle
        \oldafterchaptertitle% Old \afterchaptertitle
        \normalfont\normalsize\justifying #1% Set after-chapter paragraph
        \global\let\afterchaptertitle\oldafterchaptertitle}
    }% Restore \afterchaptertitle

\begin{document}

\afterchapterparagraph{
    \textbf{Abstract.}
    \lipsum[1][1] Someone\footnotemark{} said:
    \lipsum[1][2-7]\newline
    \centerline{\textit{htpp://imposiblewebsite.com/misinformation/news}}\\
    \par
}

\chapter*{Interesting Topic}
\footnotetext{Unknown Author}%
\lipsum[2] Note: \footnote{The reader must understand this note is important}\par
\lipsum[3] Warning:\footnote{Read carefully, hiden information about fees as follows: \lipsum[3][1-5]}\par
\lipsum[3]\par

\end{document}
```